# isinstance return improper result with nested application

Tags: python, isinstance

I developed a tool and I want to use it in another application. Now, I just copy my tool in the new application. The file architecture is shown as below.

```
.
├── inner
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── a.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── b.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── inner.py
└── outer.py
```

a.py

```
class A(object):

    def output(self):
        print('A')
```

b.py

```
from a.a import A


class B(object):

    def output(self, a):
        print('B')
        print(isinstance(a, A))
```

inner.py

```
from a.a import A
from b.b import B

a = A()
b = B()
a.output()
b.output(a)
```

B.output will check whether the second argument a is an instance of class A. Running `inner.py` under folder `inner` gives the output

```
A
B
True
```

However, when I run almost the same code `outer.py` under my new application folder, the output is not expected.

```
A
B
False
```

outer.py

```
import sys

sys.path.append('inner')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from inner.a.a import A
    from inner.b.b import B
    a = A()
    b = B()
    a.output()
    b.output(a)
```

When I add `print(a)` in outer.py, I get `<inner.a.a.A object at 0x7f45e179f2d0>`, not `a.a.A object`.

I wonder, how to integrate the inner application to make `isinstance` return a proper result? Shall I add all the folders under `inner` into `sys.path`? If so, I will choose to remove the type detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does get asked from time to time but I couldn't find a proper duplicate.

Instead of running *scripts* *within packages*, make it into an installable Python package that you will install, and use `python -m inner.inner` to run the given module as `__main__`.

Comment: A good idea I have never known before! However, I have to change the first line of `inner/b/b.py` with `from inner.a.a import A` to run `inner.py`. Is it the only way to specify the tool name at the very beginning?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala this sound interesting; can you share an example? I'm trying to better understand your suggestion

Comment: I almost forgot this question... I gave up detecting the type. While developing, import packages with relative path, thus, it's not necessary to use the tool name. Thanks!